# Searching for matching values in all class List<Object>

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects, one reference to the other. I would like to be able to using something akin to `Player.Inventory.Contain(Item.Attributes == "Sharp")`. My goal is to be able to scan a player inventory for all the items attributes and check if one or many or none are matching. This way I can dynamically change what happens depending on a character inventory.

```
class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Inventory { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
        Inventory = new List<Item>();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsCarried { get; set; }
    public List<string> Attributes { get; set; }

    public Item(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Attributes = new List<string>();
    }
    public Item(int id, string name, bool iscarried)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        IsCarried = iscarried;
        Attributes = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate LINQ operator is **`.Any()`**. I.e.

```
player.Inventory.Any(item => item.Attributes.Contains("Sharp"))
```

Please note that the *performance is poor* if the number of attributes gets large. You should prefer **`HashSet<string>`** rather than `List<string>` for `Attributes`, or `Dictionary<string,int>` if the same attribute can appear more than once.

Comment: Be aware that if you do use a hashset, then you need to change your Any() expression to a contains. LINQ relies on its ienumerable implementation to perform Any() which is O(n). Contains() is O(1).

Comment: The above syntax will still work for `HashSet` as well, since the inner predicate already uses contains. But I mixed up item with attribute in my reply - corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you could use a LINQ query with a lambda function for this.
Here is a function you could implement into your Player class to query on your items for items of a specific attribute name.

- Read-only solution with `IEnumerable<Item>`

  ```
  public IEnumerable<Item> FindMatchingItems(string attributeName) {
      return this.Items.Where(x => x.Name == attributeName).AsEnumerable();
  }
  ```
- List solution with `List<Item>`

  ```
  public List<Item> FindMatchingItems(string attributeName) {
      return this.Items.Where(x => x.Name == attributeName).ToList();
  }
  ```

Comment: Ah, my mistake. OP can use the fluent API .ToList() at the end of the .Where(), or he can change his method signature to an IEnumerable if he only needs read only.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've updated my answer to give both approaches.

Comment: What does Items represent in this situation? I have tried it and it does not work. Does not contain definition for "Items" is the error I am getting.